# Shift by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use the value from the previous group of rows, similar to `data.table::shift` but with values shifted by group. Currently, I'm doing it like this (the variable I want to create is `prev_block`):

```
dt<-data.table(expand.grid(group=c('a','b'),id=1:4, block=1:3, repn=1:3))
setorder(dt,group, id, block, repn)
dt[,prev_block:=shift(block), by=.(group, id)]
dt[1:5]

   group id block repn prev_block
1:     a  1     1    1         NA
2:     a  1     1    2          1
3:     a  1     1    3          1
4:     a  1     2    1          1
5:     a  1     2    2          2

dt[,prev_block:=prev_block[1], by=.(group, id, block)]
dt[3:8]

   group id block repn prev_block
1:     a  1     1    1         NA
2:     a  1     1    2         NA
3:     a  1     1    3         NA
4:     a  1     2    1          1
5:     a  1     2    2          1
```

Is it possible to do it with one line?

I've tried to make a function for it, but got stuck as it's not possible to modify .SD:

```
shift2<-function(.SD, x, ...){
  .SD[,tmp_var:=shift(get(x))]
  .SD[,tmp_var:=tmp_var[1],by=...]
  .SD[,tmp_var]
}
```

Comment: `dt[, pb := shift(block), by=.(group,id,repn)]`? Generally, structuring your data in this way (where some vars are repeating redundantly) is just asking for trouble.

Comment: This works only if repn is fully repeating in each block which is true for this toy data but not for the real example. As for redundancy - it's necessary if you want to do a regression for the influence of conditions of previous block on some data in the next block, for example.

Comment: Re redundancy, nothing in R forces you to only use a single table. You could make one at the appropriate level (group, id, block), define the vars there and join back only just before doing a regression: `mdt = unique(dt[, .(group, id, block)]); mdt[, pb := shift(block), by=.(group,id)]; dt[mdt, on=.(group,id,block), pb := i.pb, by=.EACHI ]`

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. I'm used to work with a single table in R, but I guess it might be time to refresh my memory of joins as the data sets are growing bigger.